# Any other way to write this statement

Tags: python, bottle, pysqlite

I'm trying to write this statement in some other way.

```
True if 'sessionid' in request.cookies else False
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: `'sessionid' in request.cookies`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
if 'sessionid' in request.cookies:
    return True
else:
    reutrn False
```

of just

```
return ('sessionid' in request.cookies)
```

Also you can assign it to a variable instead of returning it.

Comment: You can remove the first piece of code. `if True return True else return False` is perfectly redundant.